# How to get utm_content analytics on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

I've sent a newsletter with a link containing this GET variable: "utm_content=xxxx". Can I find how many users have clicked it in Google Analytics? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Acquisitions - All Traffic - Source / Medium.

Then add another dimension, click on Other and then click Acquisition.
You will see Ad Content which corresponds to **utm_content**, and Keyword corresponds to **utm_term**

[image]

Here is the [Google Analytics info](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en)

And two usefull links:

- Google [Campaign URL Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)
- Terminus [UTM URL Builder](https://www.terminusapp.com/)